# Allocating Disk Space in a Linux VM

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, fedora, disk-space-utilization

So, currently on a server I have a Fedora VM for an end user who remotes in. Unannounced to me, it was overfilled with data, and now has no more disk space. At this point, it crashed about a minute after booting up. I went into the VM and allocated more space, but it hasn't recognized this yet.

So my question is: Is there a way to have the new volume partitioned and added on to the existing root space without the machine crashing before this is accomplished?

Comment: What is the specific level of the OS?  What type of disk structure (show the fdisk) and filesystem type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is use **[gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/)**

Download the .iso, boot from the iso and extend the disk.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @AdamHart - if this answer has given you what you need, we typically ask that you give it the checkmark so that Cole can be dutifully rewarded with small reputation bonus.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have a single root partition on the VM and you have added another virtual disk drive to the VM, right?
If this is the case, you can do the following:

1. boot your VM from a live cd
2. partition the newly added drive with cfdisk, fdisk or gparted as proposed in the above answer
3. identify which of root subfolders take most of the space:

   `du -sh /*`
4. if these are one of /home/, /var/ or /tmp/, you can pretty safely move some of them to partitions created on the newly added drive. If you plan to move more than one such subfolder, you'll have to provide a separate partition for each one.
5. add a corresponding entry to /etc/fstab so that the partition is linked to the directory structure on boot.

---

Alternatively, depending on the type of virtualization software you are running, you may be able to simple extend the current drive.